# Godbolt does not show stdout

Tags: c++, compiler-explorer, godbolt

I am using https://godbolt.org/ to compile a simple C++ script but even the simplest

```
int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
}
```

When I click `Add new... --> Compiler --> Output` I get: `Compiler returned: 0`

Comment: Did you try adding a newline character at the end of the string?

Comment: Click "Output... > Run the compiled output"

Comment: Here you go https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sq4PWY

Comment: Change to MSVC and the compiler output remains, but the execution output disappears... does Compiler Explorer not support executing MSVC-compiled binaries? or is there some other setting to enable this?

Comment: Change the compiler to x86-64.  If the compiler is e.g. ARM then it probably won't provide output.

Comment: Why was this question closed? This seemingly obvious thing had me scrambling and this answer saved me. Thanks!

Comment: This is now "Output... -> Execute the code"

Comment: @Den-Jason You're right. Why not executing code under arm compiler ?

Comment: ...because the server is most likely running on a x86-64 CPU

Answer (score 8):

As @Ayxan Haqverdili told me the missing steps are `Output... > Run the compiled output`